Error : Could not get unknown property 'JacocoMerge' for root project of type org.gradle.api.project || in Gradle 8.5 with Java 21
Facing issue for JacocoMerge Task Below are version details:
Java -  21
Gradle - 8.5
Jacoco - 0.8.11
Below are gradle code
`task jacocoMerge(type:JacocoMerge){
destinationFile = file(filePath)
executionData=project.fileTree(filePath)
}
jacocoMerge.dependsOn{
subprojects*.test
}
`
expected to build success in gradle
